# How to start SQL Developer with the correct Java Version?

Tags: macos, java

I've Java 1.8 installed on my Mac OS Yosemite... and Terminal shows the following:

```
mccoy:~ daniel$ which java
/usr/bin/java
mccoy:~ daniel$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
mccoy:~ daniel$ env | grep JAVA
JAVA_OPTS=-Dnode.name=DANIEL -Xmx4g
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
mccoy:~ daniel$
```

**But SQL Developer still starts with some older Java 1.7 and complains... how can I fix this?**

[image]

Comment: See if [this post](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/07/install-oracle-sql-developer-on-os-x-mountain-lion/) helps, down at the "But My SQL Developer is Using the Wrong JDK!?" section: `[A]ll you need to do is explore the SQL Developer package, and edit the sqldeveloper-Darwin.conf file in the bin directory. Update the ‘SetJavaHome’ line to point to the 1.7 JDK`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ruffin pointed out in the comment above I had to edit the package itself! It includes a `sqldeveloper.sh` script that **changes** my currently set JAVA_HOME. Just had to comment it out!

[image]